# How to call function foo("someName") using template in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-templates

I have some dynamic elements (ie list) on the page. I want to add handler for onClick action to each elements besides each element should call this handler with specified data.

I tried this:

js:

```
$scope.data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "1",
        order: "10"
      },    
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "2",
        order: "20"
      },    
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "3",
        order: "30"
      }
    ];
```

html:

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in data" name="{{ 'name_' + item.id }}" ng-click="onClick({{ '\'name_' + item.id +'\'' }})" value="item">
    Item name is "{{ item.name }}"
  </div>
```

When I am observing dom I see correct html: ng-click="onClick('name_1')", but when I click on the row, nothing happens. Why? (also, I am getting long red error by angularJS in console, saying that I am really wrong)

How I can achieve what I want? I don't say that it must be done by my approach. May be there are another approach - better then mine (like using some angular property maybe (like ng-repeat has: $index))

Comment: Why can't you just call onClick(item.id), and have it create the needed string 'name_id' itself?

Comment: Because function is already used in other elements. Usage is: onFocus('elementName'). Other elements even don't have id's.

Comment: So make a new function that creates the string and calls your other function.

Comment: Maybe it is good idea, but not in this case. Name is bit complicated and depends on some factors. Is it possible to format name when calling function in angular?

Comment: I need at least 5 functions with 99% same contents, except formatting input part.

Answer (score 2):

`ngClick` directive needs an expression in it. You should not interpolate anything inside of it. So it should be:

```
ng-click="onClick('name_' + item.id)"
```